# Gravity Form dynamic population and logic conditional in php

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin

sorry for the noob question and the wrong code. 
I need that a gravity form field is populated with a different value depending on the amount entered by the user in a number field. Is possible?

I try this code but only with the first value does it work, how can I write it correctly?

```html
add_filter( 'gform_field_value_custom_price', 'my_price' );
function my_price() {
    $master = rgpost( `input_22`);
 if ( $master < 51 ) {
    return 0.80;
    } elseif ( $master > 50 && < 201  {
 return 0.60;
    } 
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since you're populating static values, you could feasibly just create two different fields, each with their unique amount (0.80 or 0.60) and then use conditional logic on each field to show/hide the correct field dependent on the value entered in the Number field.

If the field you're attempting to populate is a Product field, you might consider [Gravity Forms Conditional Pricing](https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-conditional-pricing/) which would allow to change the price dynamically on a single field rather than requiring two different fields.